# How to commit code separately for app project with nested framework project in Xcode

Tags: xcode, frameworks, git-commit

I used the instructions in [Apps with Multiple Xcode Projects](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2435/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017543-CH1-PROJ_CONFIG-APPS_WITH_MULTIPLE_XCODE_PROJECTS) to set up an app project with a nested framework project in Xcode. The project navigator looks like this:

[image: App project with nested framework project]

When I make changes to files in the framework and/or files in the app, clicking on *Source Control > Commit* in the Xcode menu brings up the Commit window showing all the files I have modified (both the app *and* the framework) with a checkbox next to them.

How can I commit files for the app and the framework **separately**? Whatever commit message I write would be applied to both projects in the commit, which wouldn't be correct. What is the proper thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling with this for a couple of weeks, I just found out the answer on my own.

Using the example where an app project (MyApp) has a nested framework project (MyFramework.xcodeproj):

[image: App project with nested framework project]

if you made changes to both the app project as well as the framework project, clicking on *Source Control > Commit* in the Xcode menu brings up the Commit window showing **all** the files with a checkbox next to them. This means that the commit message will apply to both the app project and the framework project, which wouldn't be correct!

The way to commit the modified files in the framework project **separately** (using the example above) is to Ctrl-click on MyFramework (yellow folder) under MyFramework.xcodeproj in the project navigator. In the menu that pops up, click on *Source Control > Commit n files*:

[image: project-specific popup menu]

The Commit window appears showing all the files in both the app project and the framework project, **BUT** only the files in MyFramework project that need to be committed are pre-selected. Add the Commit message appropriate to the framework project and commit the files.

Repeat by Ctrl-click'ing on MyApp (yellow folder) in the project navigator and then clicking on *Source Control > Commit n files*...